# How to prevent the entity from sinking to the ground? - PocketMine

Tags: pocketmine

[Here is my entity you can look at this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFKpE.png)

> on that image my entity is not normally can stand on the ground, and I have added code to spawn the entity and i want to be able to stand normally in the ground the entity how to do this ?
> can someone help me ?